# Trying to get db row count value updated

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to receive in my home the total lines that exist in my database. When I run the app for the first time in my text widget appears "null", it only changes if I go to another page and go back and the value is not updated. I add another line to bd and when I go back the value goes from null to 28 for example but there is already +1 line.

In home I am getting the value inside initState with setState. Any suggestion? Thank you!!

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
ContactHelper helper = ContactHelper();
List<Contact> listaSigilos = List();
int count;


@override
initState() {
super.initState();
setState(() {
  helper.getAllContacts().then((list) {
    listaSigilos = list;
    count = listaSigilos.length;
    print(list);
    print("count: $count");

  });
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NovoSigilo()));
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Stuff to do"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: <Widget>[],
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Active"),
          Text("$count",//Show row count here
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all never use `setState()` directly inside `initState()` method. Second, you were only listening to the database inside `initState()` which gets called just once, I have created a new method called `_fetchData()`, which is put inside `initState()` as well as one you come back from your second page.

```
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  _fetchData(); // fetch data in the start
}

void _fetchData() {
  helper.getAllContacts().then((list) {
    listaSigilos = list;
    count = listaSigilos.length;
    print(list);
    print("count: $count");
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

Update your `floatingActionButton` to

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NovoSigilo())).then((value) {
      _fetchData(); // fetch data after coming back to this page
    });
  },
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
)
```

Comment: That worked great! I need to practice more. Thanks!!